# Which AD&D book contains the Cavalier, Acrobat, Barbarian, and other classes popularized by the cartoon?

Tags: class, adnd-1e, product-identification

What's the name of the AD&D book (1st Edition) that has the other character classes that were popularized in the Saturday morning cartoon?

I'm talking about the Cavalier, Acrobat, Barbarian, and others.

It's been 25 years since I've played (starting up again, because my kids found my old books and wouldn't let me rest until I came up with an adventure for them) and I can't find or even remember the name of that reference manual.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The 1985 book [*Unearthed Arcana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unearthed_Arcana#Advanced_Dungeons_.26_Dragons) book contained the Barbarian, Thief-Acrobat, and Cavalier:

> Unearthed Arcana includes the **barbarian** (found *in Dragon* #63), **cavalier** (found in *Dragon* #72), and **thief-acrobat** (found in *Dragon* #69) character classes, and also includes expansions and revisions of the druid and ranger classes.

Answer (score 17):

You're thinking of [*Unearthed Arcana*](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/43604/unearthed-arcana), supplement first published in 1985:

[image: Unearthed Arcana cover]
<sub>(source: [boardgamegeek.com](http://images.boardgamegeek.com/images/pic499289_t.jpg))</sub>

*Unearthed Arcana* contained the Cavalier, Barbarian, and Thief-Acrobat, as well as new material for existing classes and races, race variants such as the High Elves and Drow as PC races, new spells, new weapons, weapon specialization rules, and the infamous Comeliness ability score.

Comment: Ah....Comeliness.  That brings back memories, none of them good.

Comment: Yeah. That is the one notable "innovation" that was a total flop. Other things that UA introduced—like Drow as PCs, weapon specialisation, and sub-classes of main classes—are still with us all the way into *D&D 4th edition*.

Comment: Technically, Comeliness was introduced in Oriental Adventures before UA, although I wouldn't be surprised if it showed up in Dragon before that.

Answer (score 16):

This isn't what you're asking, but I figure it was a good place for a bit of extra info.  Those all came from Dragon Magazine before Unearthed Arcana was published.

The barbarian was in Dragon #63, the Thief-Acrobat was in Dragon #69 and the Cavalier was in Dragon #72.

Comment: Most of the Unearthed Arcana content appeared in Dragon before UA was published, and Gygax was quite open about the fact that this was the stuff that would be in the book. He was confident, and rightly so, that subscribers would want all the content in a single bound source book, even though they had it in their magazines. The material in Dragon helped build excitement for the new book.